# Fitting two copper corners without screwing

Tags: copper-pipe

I need to fit two of these peces together without screwing them one into another (lack of space). Is there a piece that can be put in between which can be screwed in place?
[image]

Here is the real case [image]

Comment: Should have more information, but there are loads of different fittings/adapters.  Go to your local plumbing shop and can spend hours checking them all out.  Ask a person there and they will suggest the best that will work for what you need.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: a small piece of copper tube and solder it.

Comment: How Should I clarify more? Having two pieces as in the image above, in order to fit them together I need to screw one into the other. This is not possible due to narrow space. I need another way to do that. @SolarMike, soldering is not possible because I don't have the equipment and the experience to do that.

Comment: You asked for other methods - I gave you one possibility and you did not mention that you lacked equipment. What other skills do you possess?

Comment: @SolarMike I appreciate the response, thank you. crip659 seems to be  a fit answer for what I need.

Comment: Some kind of PEX or SharkBite connector?

Comment: Usually if two pieces need to be screwed together in a tight space, you would screw them in the open and then place them.  Most threaded fittings have a small range to turn and be leak free, a quarter to half a turn in both directions.

Comment: @Huesmann The connector is exactly as in the picture for some 15mm copper piping.

Comment: @yonutix is your copper piping threaded somehow?

Comment: @crip659 I screwed several pieces together in the open, but the final part I must fit in place.

Comment: @Huesmann The part I'm trying to fit is not threaded, I'm using compression fittings because I'm a beginner and it seems the safest way. The other part I'm trying to fit my part to is soldered in place and I can't move it.

Comment: @yonutix then it may behoove you to show us the actual things you want to connect...

Comment: @Huesmann I added the actual case. As you can see I've put together the parts on the left, and I need to fit it somehow in the old pipe.

Comment: @yonutix are you saying there isn't enough room to turn the tee once it's been threaded to the valve?  (Also, I'm not seeing any elbows in the "to be replaced" bit.)  What exactly are you trying to do with the two new tees in your pic?

Comment: @Huesmann Turning the tee only once is not enough, it will leak, it has to be tight isn't it? The new T should have an additional pipe on the exit and replace the PEX with copper.

Comment: @yonutix Hard to tell from your pic, but it looks like the valve is diagonal to the wall. Is there room to add an *extension* off the valve, to get the tee further away from the wall, and hopefully enough room to thread it tight?

Comment: I was hoping that there is a piece similar to how the shower head fits to the hose without having to twist the hose.

Comment: Is the part in your hand oriented the way it will be installed? It's hard to tell for certain exactly which part of the shiny new will attach to what part of the crusty old...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, what you want is a "Union". It's a piece of pipe with threaded nuts at each end. You stick the union in where you want it, then you can individually screw each nut to the existing pipe. Often, hand-tight will be just fine, but you may need a wrench. Whatever tools you used to tighten up the "new work" piece should be fine to tighten up the union.

Generally, unions are straight, so you may have to put in another couple of elbows to get to the point where you can put in a straight union to complete the plumbing.

Answer (score 1):

The parts shown in the first picture are quite unlike the parts in the second picture, so that wasn't a helpful or relevant first picture... And you are not showing the whole situation to be replaced, since your new assembly appears to extend off the picture to the right if placed where the "will be replaced" item is circled, implying that more is to be replaced right of it, but not circled.

It appears that your old parts involve compression fittings and adapters. Since compression fittings will turn if loosened, you can loosen the compression fittings and tighten the threaded adapter (where needed) to the new part, then tighten the compression fittings. You may need a new adapter on the lower connection, which seems to have a compression to female pipe thread adapter while your new pipe appears to have only male pipe threads there.